# Equivalent type Boolean in Swift 2

Tags: swift, boolean, swift2, xcode7

I'm trying to covert the lines below from Swift to Swift 2

```
var cfstatus = CFWriteStreamOpen(stream) as Boolean

// connection fail
if cfstatus == 0 {
    println("Not connected")
    return
}
```

In Swift 2 there is no 'Boolean' type.
I have tried to use 'Bool' but that gave an error:

`Binary operator == cannot be applied to operands of type Bool and Int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of `CFWriteStreamOpen` is

```
public func CFWriteStreamOpen(stream: CFWriteStream!) -> Bool
```

There is no type casting needed.

```
let cfstatus = CFWriteStreamOpen(stream)
// connection fail
if cfstatus == false { // or if !cfstatus {
    println("Not connected")
    return
}
```

Xcode provides a simple lookup of the declaration by <kbd>⌘</kbd>-clicking on the symbol.

You get the error message because you're trying to compare a `Bool` (cfstatus) with an `Int` (0) which is forbidden in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

`Bool` is the correct type; `Boolean` does not exist by default.

The above comparison with `==` fails because the operands have different types (`Bool` and `Int`, in this case). Try this instead:

```
var cfstatus = CFWriteStreamOpen(stream)

// connection fail
if !cfstatus {
    println("Not connected")
    return
}
```

Comment: ... and remove the `as Boolean`. Btw, `Boolean` did exist in pre-Swift 2.